# Docker Communication between service of one stack to another

Tags: docker, resttemplate, service-discovery, docker-stack

I am trying out a simple service discovery scenario using different docker stacks.
 Let's assume I am having 2 stacks. For simplicity purpose,I am naming them as stackA and stackB. 
StackA has a service called 'serviceA' and StackB has a service called 'serviceB'.
ServiceA and serviceB are having a simple RestApplication.

Now I want to call serviceB from serviceA. I understand the concept of docker service discovery and followed the docker official document but unable to call serviceB.
[discovering-services-or-containers-on-another-stack](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/apps/service-links/#discovering-services-or-containers-on-another-stack)

As per official doc, I am using **serviceB.StackB** , but couldn't do.

Unable to understand the reason.Few points:
1.each stack creates its own network. Is it happening because both stacks are not in same network?
2. What if I need them in the different network only, how do I call different services

Comment: Are you using docker cloud? Or running on your server?

Comment: You tagged your question with "resttemplate" so I assume you're using Spring Boot? If so, have a look at "Eureka", it is the best practice for discover microservices with Spring. These microservices can be put into their own docker container and will speak to each other autmatically.

Comment: @leodotcloud I am not using docker cloud.  Its having 3 nodes, 1 manager, and 2 workers

Comment: @BennettDams Yes, I am using Spring-Boot. However, I am not using Netflix OSS.
If I use netflix, I would have gone with feign client.

Comment: @VivekShukla Based on the documentation link you provided, I think service.stack resolution could be a feature of Docker cloud, not for custom setups? But I haven't tried myself though.

Comment: @leodotcloud I have already mentioned service.stack in my question which is not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution to above problem.
You need to follow 2 steps:

1. The services which want to communicate with each other should belong to same network

```
version: "3"
  services:
    serviceA:
    ....
    networks:
    - YOUR_NETWORK
networks:
  YOUR_NETWORK:
    external: true
```

2. If you deploy your stack, your service is always prefixed with stack name such as **STACK-NAME_SERVICE-NAME**. 
for discovering another service, just use STACK-NAME_SERVICE-NAME:PORT